# Replicating JSON.Stringify

Tags: json, recursion, stringify

I have a practice problem and I need to replicate JSON.stringify, without actually using JSON.stringify. I was having trouble getting to the return value when it's an object that your  inputting into the function. For example, if you insert

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
JSON.stringify (obj); // returns "{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}"
```

That being said, I was trying to use a for in loop to set the property to the string value of the object that's being passed through. I was doing this only for an object container, but the function should actually work with anything you pass through it and it would JSON.stringify it.

```
var stringifyJSON = function(obj) {
 var newObj = {};
 for (var prop in obj){
    newObj ={
    stringProp:obj[prop]
    };
}
 return newObj;
};
```

I think I have the array portion down. I'm pretty terrible with object traversing. The result here is 'Object {stringProp:3}'. This is a practice problem within a recursion problem set, so I think they don't want me to use a loop. I was just trying to make it a little simpler by looping it, and then I would try to replicate it through recursion.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
B

Answer (score -1):

Since it is a practice problem I'll just try to point you in the right direction:

You will need a loop in the code, as you will be required to recursively loop over each property in the object.

As for the recursive part, first you need to define your 'base case'. What is the condition based on the input that should not result in a recursive call? I'll give you a big hint, it's when the argument is not an object.

The tricky part for you is determining how you are going to be appending the resulting string from the recursive calls.

Some basic template code to start you off:

```
function myStringify( obj ) {

    if ( typeof obj !== 'object' ) {
        // base case
        return ""+obj;
    }

    var str = "";
    for ( var prop in obj ) {            
        if ( obj.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
            // recursive calls and string formatting magic
         }
    }
    return str;
}
```